# How to remove controller names from rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I would like to trim down the routes on my application so that:

`http://myapplication.com/users/peter/questions/how-do-i-create-urls`

becomes...

`http://myapplication.com/peter/how-do-i-create-urls`

I have a users controller and would like it to be resourceful. Users also have a nested resource called questions.

**Basic routes file**

Without any URL trimming, the routes file looks like this:

```
...
resources :users do
  resources :questions
end
```

However the URLs from this take the form of

`http://myapplication.com/users/peter/questions/how-do-i-create-urls`

rather than

`http://myapplication.com/peter/how-do-i-create-urls`

**Partial success**
I have tried doing the following:

```
...
resources :users, :path => '' do
  resources :questions
end
```

This works and produces:

`http://myapplication.com/peter/questions/how-do-i-create-urls`

However if I try:

```
...
resources :users, :path => '' do
  resources :questions, :path => ''
end
```

Then things start to go wrong.

Is this the right approach and if so, can it be made to work with nested resources too?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The way you are doing it should work. I don't know what problem you are experiencing but if you copied the example code from your app directly then it might be because of the extra `end` that you have put in your routes. It should probably look like this:

```
resource :users, :path => '' do
  resource :questions, :path => ''
end
```

Another thing that could be the cause and that you need to be vary careful about is that these routes pretty much catches all requests and you should have them last in your routes.rb so that other routes matches first. Take this scenario for example:

```
resource :users, :path => '' do
  resource :questions, :path => ''
end

resources :posts
```

If you do it this way then no request will ever be routed to the Posts controller since a request to /posts/1 will be sent to the Questions controller with :user_id => 'posts', :id => 1

Edit:

Also, I now noticed that you use resource instead of resources. Don't know if that is intended or if it is a mistake.

Comment: Danne, this is very helpful and reassuring. You were right on both the pluralization of resource's' and the extra end, I've fixed both of them. On doing a rake routes I also discovered that they did look as expected but that `user_questions` was actually being matched before `user` so I'm going to try removing the (superfluous) `user_questions` route. On a separate note, do you know how to change the key of the parameter variable that's passed to the controller so that it can be `:user_slug` rather than just `:id`?

Comment: That `user_questions` is mapped before `user` is nothing strange because the route mapper will capture the block before it adds the resource routes. Not much you can do about it and it should not cause any problems anyway. Regarding the :id parameter, don't actually know about that. I have never seen any way of changing it but I'm not sure.

Comment: It works like a charm for me. And it stays in the restful spirit. Love it.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to both @mark and @DanneManne for their help. With their input and a little more tweaking I got it all working. It's not exactly trivial but I'm not sure you could make it much shorter either:

---

**Final working code**

```
# setup the basic resources while holding some back for creation below
resources :users, :except => [:show, :index, :new, :create], :path => '/' do
  resources :questions, :except => [:show]
end

# for clarity, pick out routes that would otherwise go 
# to root (such as new_user => '/new')
resources :users, :only => [:index, :new, :create]


# setup questions#show to give clean URLS
match ':user_id/:question_id', :as => :user_question, 
                               :via => :get,
                               :controller => :questions, 
                               :action => :show

# setup users#show method to give clean URLS
match ':user_id', :as => :user, 
                  :via => :get, 
                  :controller => :user, 
                  :action => :show
```

**Rake Routes output**

```
    user_questions GET    /:user_id/questions(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"questions"}
                   POST   /:user_id/questions(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"questions"}
 new_user_question GET    /:user_id/questions/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"questions"}
edit_user_question GET    /:user_id/questions/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"questions"}
     user_question PUT    /:user_id/questions/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"questions"}
                   DELETE /:user_id/questions/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"questions"}
         edit_user GET    /:id/edit(.:format)                    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
              user PUT    /:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
                   DELETE /:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
             users GET    /users(.:format)                       {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
                   POST   /users(.:format)                       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
          new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
     user_question GET    /:user_id/:question_id(.:format)       {:controller=>"questions", :action=>"show"}
              user GET    /:user_id(.:format)                    {:controller=>"user", :action=>"show"}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about the nesting but try

```
:path => '/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd add another possible solution, in case anybody else arrives from Google at a later date.

After looking at [this nested resource article](http://jasoncodes.com/posts/rails-3-nested-resource-slugs), this could be a cleaner solution with *almost* the same flexibility in routes:

```
resources :users, :path => ''
resources :users, :path => '', :only => [] do
  resources :questions, :path => '', :except => [:index]
```

Basically, by including the second parent block, the child resources aren't yielded before the parent resources.

This particular example also assumes that having complete routes for the parent block is more crucial than those for the child. Consequently, the child block is limited from having an index, but this might be acceptable, depending on the situation.