# How To Remove Controller Names From Multiple Rails Routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, controller, routes

I have two models in my app: **articles** and **pages**. I'd like the url to look like this;

```
www.mysite.com/this-is-the-title-of-the-article  (articles#show)
www.mysite.com/about-me (pages#show)
```

A bit similar to regular wordpress routes, but with rails this seems like a big hassle. I've found a working solution, but it could probably be improved upon. Here's what I got;

**Inside routes.rb;**

```
  resources :articles, :pages
  # this redirects /:id requests to my StaticPagesController
  match ':id' => 'static_pages#redirect', :via => [:get]
  resources :articles, :only => [:show], :path => '', as: "articles_show"
  resources :pages, :only => [:show], :path => '', as: "pages_show"
```

**Inside StaticPagesController;**

```
 # Basically, it checks if there's a page or article with the given id and renders the corresponding show. Else it shows the 404 
    def redirect
        @article = Article.where(slug_nl: params[:id]).first || Article.where(slug_en: params[:id]).first
        @page = Page.where(slug: params[:id]).first
        if !@page.nil?
          @page = Page.friendly.find(params[:id])
          render(:template => 'pages/show')
        elsif !@article.nil?
          @article = Article.friendly.find(params[:id])
          @relatedarticles = Article.where(category: @article.category).uniq.limit(6).where.not(id: @article)
          render(:template => 'articles/show')
        else
          render(:template => 'common/404', :status => 404)
        end
      end
```

**Note:** I've swapped out the id for articles and pages with the title attribute (using the friendly_id gem). The articles are also in two languages (therefore I check for both slugs)

Any idea's? I've already tried some of these;

- http://blog.arkency.com/2014/01/short-urls-for-every-route-in-your-rails-app/
- [How to remove controller names from rails routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369476/how-to-remove-controller-names-from-rails-routes)
- http://base0.net/posts/two-ways-for-rails-multiple-model-url-aliases/

But they didn't quite did the trick so far. Thanks :) ♥

Comment: How did the constraints solution described in http://blog.arkency.com/2014/01/short-urls-for-every-route-in-your-rails-app/ not worked?

Comment: The error was on my side, I've actually been able to solve the problem using your solution!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I improved the solution, but it still doesn't feel 100% rails-y. But, here's what I did to get;

- /page-title **(pages#show)**
- en/this-is-the-article **(articles#show, en
  locale)**
- nl/dit-is-de-titel **(articles#show, nl locale)**

Note: I've swapped out the id for articles and pages with the title attribute (using the friendly_id gem). The articles are also in two languages (therefore I check for both slugs)

**Routing.rb** (modified from blog.arkency.com/2014/01/short-urls-for-every-route-in-your-rails-app

```
 resources :users, :projects, :testimonials, :articles, :pages
  class ArticleUrlConstrainer
    def matches?(request)
      id = request.path.gsub("/", "")[2..-1]
      @article = Article.where(slug_nl: id).first || Article.where(slug_en: id).first
      if I18n.locale == :en
        @article = Article.find_by(slug_en: id) || Article.find_by(slug_nl: id)
      else
        @article = Article.find_by(slug_nl: id) || Article.find_by(slug_en: id)
      end
    end
  end

  constraints(ArticleUrlConstrainer.new) do
    match '/:id', :via => [:get], to: "articles#show"
  end

  class PageUrlConstrainer
    def matches?(request)
      id = request.path.gsub("/", "")[2..-1]
      @page = Page.friendly.find(id)
    end
  end

  constraints(PageUrlConstrainer.new) do
    match '/:id', :via => [:get], to: "pages#show"
  end

  resources :articles, :only => [:show], :path => '', as: "articles_show"
  resources :pages, :only => [:show], :path => '', as: "pages_show"
```

**Final**

- http://www.truetech.be/nl/10-essentiele-elementen-van-een-goede-website **(article#show, nl locale)**
- http://www.truetech.be/nl/webdesign-lier **(page#show)**