# add a prefix to ID in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

At the moment my routes are such :

```
users/id/order/id/product/id
```

As per this thread [How to remove controller names from rails routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369476/how-to-remove-controller-names-from-rails-routes) I plan to remove the controller name for 'users' and replace it with the ID instead like :

```
id/order/id/product/id
```

Though starting an address with an pure numeric ID is a bit confusing and I would like to have something like this instead :

```
user_id/order/id/product/id
```

How is it possible to prefix my user ID with "user_" ?

EDIT

Here is the bit of my routes handling the users model (named "client")

```
resources :client, controller: "clients", param: :hashed_id do
      resources :bien, controller: "biens", param: :hashed_id do
        member do
          patch 'updatedetails'
        end
      end      
    end
```

So an example of working url :

```
myapp.com/client/do2rt/bien/ff34h
```

I would like instead :

```
myapp.com/client_do2rt/bien/ff34h
```

and the params for client still being "do2rt". Otherwise I guess I could make my slug the full `client_do2rt` but it looks a bit unnecessary

Comment: can you show us your `routes.rb` file

Comment: `resources :users, :key => :user_id` that should hekp

Comment: actually my ID is a slug (`hashed_id`). Can you please develop a bit on key ? basically I want a prefix that would make something like "client_#{hashed_id}" and the param still being `hashed_id`.

Comment: Can you show an example of url you want to be working. And what url is working at this moment?

Comment: What's the end goal here? You're still keeping the ID in the URL, just removing the `users` portion? If you're going to remain RESTful, you should keep the route as-is. Are you sure you aren't looking for a tenancy option, where visiting `/order/:id/product/:id` returns records scoped to the `current_user`?

Comment: Hi Daniel, it's mostly for the looks actually : have a specific Id prefix that I can change easily (from `client_do2rt` to `utilisateur_do2rt` or anything else later). And because the REST is not useful for the User model (as it is very private data, no need of index etc...) so I am removing the ability for my visitors to try something like `myapp.com/client/`